# Import Hyper-V guest when it wasn't gracefully exported?

Tags: hyper-v

The export/import story provided by Hyper-V by default seems to be rather restrictive.

What if the Host A has a hardware failure? I will want to transplant the hard disks where the VHDs and config files reside into Host B, right?

But then there is seemingly no way to get those guests loaded back into the Hyper-V management console. The import tool just barfs when directed to the files.

Is this a joke or am I missing something?

Comment: I loved "gracefully"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed. It's easier to just create a new VM, and mount the old guest's VHDs to the new VM.

Comment: I've done that in the past though and it's totally DESTROYED the network adapter configuration. Sometimes its got into an unrecoverable state where all networking connectivity is lost and no matter how many times you try to reinstall the Hyper-V NIC drivers or whatever, it is no good.

Comment: yep, there is a way around that: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/virtualization/q-i-recreated-my-hyper-v-guest-configuration-and-it-lost-its-network-configuration-why-.aspx

Comment: The XML hacking solution wouldn't be so bad if the file was organised in such a way that I could use a File Merge tool like P4Merge or BeyondCompare on it. But it seems every file has a wildly different schema composed of lots of GUIDs. Merging is pretty much impossible.

Comment: I do this a lot and have never bothered with the XML editing solution. I just create the new VM without a NIC at first and boot, delete the hidden old NIC from Device Manager, then shut down, add a new NIC to the VM and boot and configure it properly. This works reliably. It seems it shouldn't be necessary to start with no NIC and delete the old one but sometimes windows seems to hang if I don't.

Comment: The windows IT Pro link is now: https://www.itprotoday.com/server-virtualization/q-i-recreated-my-hyper-v-guest-configuration-and-it-lost-its-network

Comment: I had to do this.  Note that it does destroy your network interface, so you'll need to know the IP address and other settings of the old interface to put it back.  This is typical Microsoft unsupportable implementations.  How stupid that you have to export to import?  Just incredibly stupid.  This type of poor implementation is part of what has convinced me to get out of the tech industry.